# How to assign sequentially numbered id attribute to XML file with R?

Tags: r, xml, text, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<book id="1">
<sentence>word word word <lemma>word</lemma></sentence>
<sentence>word word word <lemma>word</lemma></sentence>
<sentence>word word word <lemma>word</lemma></sentence>
</book>
<book id="2">
<sentence>word word word <lemma>word</lemma></sentence>
<sentence>word word word <lemma>word</lemma></sentence>
<sentence>word word word <lemma>word</lemma></sentence>
</book>
<book id="3">
<sentence>word word word <lemma>word</lemma></sentence>
<sentence>word word word <lemma>word</lemma></sentence>
<sentence>word word word <lemma>word</lemma></sentence>
</book>
```

I want to use R to add an id attribute to each sentence and lemma object so that they are sequentially numbered, i.e.,

```
<book id="1">
<sentence id="1">word word word <lemma id="1">word</lemma></sentence>
<sentence id="2">word word word <lemma id="2">word</lemma></sentence>
<sentence id="3">word word word <lemma id="3">word</lemma></sentence>
</book>
<book id="2">
<sentence id="1">word word word <lemma id="1">word</lemma></sentence>
<sentence id="2">word word word <lemma id="2">word</lemma></sentence>
<sentence id="3">word word word <lemma id="3">word</lemma></sentence>
</book>
<book id="3">
<sentence id="1">word word word <lemma id="1">word</lemma></sentence>
<sentence id="2">word word word <lemma id="2">word</lemma></sentence>
<sentence id="3">word word word <lemma id="3">word</lemma></sentence>
</book>
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example using `xml2` and `purrr` (for mapping over nodes). First, the input data.

```
library(xml2)
library(purrr)
xx <- read_xml('
<books>
  <book id="1">
    <sentence>word word word <lemma>word</lemma></sentence>
    <sentence>word word word <lemma>word</lemma></sentence>
    <sentence>word word word <lemma>word</lemma></sentence>
  </book>
  <book id="2">
    <sentence>word word word <lemma>word</lemma></sentence>
    <sentence>word word word <lemma>word</lemma></sentence>
    <sentence>word word word <lemma>word</lemma></sentence>
    </book>
    <book id="3">
      <sentence>word word word <lemma>word</lemma></sentence>
      <sentence>word word word <lemma>word</lemma></sentence>
      <sentence>word word word <lemma>word</lemma></sentence>
    </book>
</books>')
```

Then you can do

```
xx %>% 
  xml_find_all("book") %>% 
  map(function(book) {
    book %>% 
      xml_find_all(".//lemma") %>% 
      imap(~xml_set_attr(.x, "id", .y))
  })
```

You look through all of the books, find the lemmas and add an index.

You can verify the result by saving and then re-reading the data back in

```
write_xml(xx, "new.xml")
cat(readLines("new.xml"), sep="\n")
```

which gives

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
  <book id="1">
    <sentence>word word word <lemma id="1">word</lemma></sentence>
    <sentence>word word word <lemma id="2">word</lemma></sentence>
    <sentence>word word word <lemma id="3">word</lemma></sentence>
  </book>
  <book id="2">
    <sentence>word word word <lemma id="1">word</lemma></sentence>
    <sentence>word word word <lemma id="2">word</lemma></sentence>
    <sentence>word word word <lemma id="3">word</lemma></sentence>
  </book>
  <book id="3">
    <sentence>word word word <lemma id="1">word</lemma></sentence>
    <sentence>word word word <lemma id="2">word</lemma></sentence>
    <sentence>word word word <lemma id="3">word</lemma></sentence>
  </book>
</books>
```